# How do I add a cell to UITableViewController using Eureka?

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I'm trying to program a table view app that takes data from a Eureka form, and creates cells based off that data. I am having trouble figuring out how to create a table view cell and insert it, using the user-provided data from the form. Code below.

```
    +++ Section()
        <<< ButtonRow() { row in
            row.title = "Save Entry"
            }.onCellSelection { (cell,row) in
                self.submit()
    }
}

func submit() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        var entry = Entry(name: self.name, size: self.size, dateComponents: self.date)
    })
}
```

Having a hard time getting the data from above to below.

```
class SneakerTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var entries = Array<Entry>()

@objc func insert() {
    let insertionIndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: entries.count - 1, section: 0)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [insertionIndexPath as IndexPath], with: .automatic)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return CustomTableViewController.entries.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell



    let entry = entries.last

    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy"

    customCell.nameLabel.text = entry.name
    customCell.sizeLabel.text = String(format: "%.1f", entry.size)
    customCell.dateLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: entry.date)

    customCell.customTableViewController = self

    return customCell
}
}
```

Thank you! Any and all help is greatly appreciated and please let me know if there is anything I can share or answer to clarify!

Comment: What is the issue that you're facing?

Comment: Creating a new tableview cell using data from the form. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: What is data from the form here? Your question needs more clarity. You might have created a model to use as `dataSource` of `tableView`, add that here.

Comment: The form creates a custom `Entry` object that holds the data. I'm not sure how to create a cell from that object. It's shown in the top code segment.